# define a drop-down list using constants and array in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm new to Yii framework.
I'm studying 'Web Application Development with Yii and PHP'.
This book defines CONSTANTS and Uses it in an array to provide a drop-down list. 
**WHY? 
Why is it valuable?
AND How it attribute new values in array definition to CONSTANTS?**

Here is code:

```
class Issue extends CActiveRecord{
....

const TYPE_BUG=0;
const TYPE_FEATURE=1;
const TYPE_TASK=2;
public function getTypeOptions()
{
return array(
self::TYPE_BUG=>'Bug',
self::TYPE_FEATURE=>'Feature',
self::TYPE_TASK=>'Task',
);

....
}
```

Comment: Because [magic numbers are bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MagicNumber), mmkay.

Comment: Also if its worth it, you can have a [lookup table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alternative to using constants is to use what are know as magic numbers, which is "*direct usage of a number in your code*". Imagine we are creating a user registration form, and we want to limit the maximum number of characters for the username field. We could do something like this:

```
if (strlen($model->username) > 10){
    // username is too long
}
```

There is essentially nothing wrong with that piece of code. The problem comes in when you use this same value in multiple places, for example when the user updates their details and changes their username. You would have the same comparison again.

Now imagine that for some reason we decide that usernames can now be **12** characters long. You will have to go and find all the places in your code that uses this value and update them. While in our example here, that isn't really an issue, imagine doing this on a HUGE system with hundreds of references to this value. You can't simply find and replace the value **10** with **12** because that would almost certainly break the system. So you have to locate and interpret every occurrence of this value.

Using a constant in the place of this value would save us a lot of time, and would make for more understandable code that is easier to maintain. Eg:

```
const MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH = 10;

if (strlen($model->username) > MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH){
    // username is too long
}
```

A good definition of magic numbers is:

```
The term magic number also refers to the bad programming practice of using
numbers directly in source code without explanation. In most cases this makes
programs harder to read, understand, and maintain. Although most guides make an
exception for the numbers zero and one, it is a good idea to define all other
numbers in code as named constants.
```

As a side note, I am one of the technical reviewers for that book (Web Application Development with Yii and PHP)

Comment: I knew benefits of using Constants but I didn't recognize relation between Using it in an array for a drop-down list. I understand According to your answer it will be valuable when we use the drop-down list in many places(for easy altering in future). I seems logical.
Thank you again.